# how to show the progress bar before playing the video

Tags: android, video-streaming, progressdialog

i want to show the progress dialog before playing video. i tried below link example for playing video.

http://davanum.wordpress.com/2009/12/04/android-%E2%80%93-videomusic-player-sample-take-2/

it works but it takes more time to take for playing video so i want to show a progress dialog before start the video. so please tel me how to show the progress dialog before playing the video.

Thank you.

Best Regards.

Comment: a better approach here http://www.quicktips.in/how-to-show-progressbar-while-loading-a-video-in-android-videoview/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

First, declare the progress dialog

```
private static ProgressDialog progressDialog;
```

Then, in onCreate, before calling runOnUiThread, start the dialog

```
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "Loading...", true);
```

In playVideo, set a OnPreparedListener that will dismiss the dialog when the video is ready to play

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer arg0) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        mVideoView.start();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

IMHO in this case it's more graceful to use ProgressBar widget insted of Progress dialog. It looks better on the video surface. You could add the progress bar to your activity's layout above the VideoView:

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progress" 
    android:indeterminate="true" 
    android:indeterminateBehavior="repeat" 
    android:layout_width="100dp" 
    android:layout_height="100dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">
</ProgressBar>
```

In onCreate, before calling runOnUiThread, show the progress:

```
mProgress = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress);
mProgress.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
```

In onPrepared callback hide the progress:

```
mProgress.setVisibility( View.INVISIBLE );
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest looking at the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), this seems ideally suited for doing video pre-loading. This will allow you to keep your UI thread stable during loading. There is an example of using the AsyncTask method [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/07/read-rss-in-background-using-asynctask.html).

To add a progress dialog:

- Create a private [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)
  object as part of an extension class
  of AsyncTask.
- In the `onPreExecute()` method you can perform progress dialog setting
  up, such as:
  `pd.setMessage(...) pd.setTitle(...) pd.show(...)`
- In the `onPostExecute(...)` method, dismiss the dialog: `pd.dismiss();`

Additionally, you can update the progress dialog using its `incrementProgressBy(...)` method, or alternately have a looping animation using the `setIndeterminate(...)` method. Giving the user feedback of the loaded progress is a good idea in UI design :)

I hope this helps!